# Ubuntu Terminal Colouring

Tags: command-line, prompt

I got this snippet of code from @mdo (http://markdotto.com) and optimized it to Ubuntu. But now when I type something and erase with backspace, the whole line is erased. I don't know too much of bash and stuff, so you can help me?

```
PS1='\[\e[0;35m⌘\e[m  \e[0;36m\w/\e[m \e[0;33m`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E  s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`\e[m\]'
```

The problem is basically when doing backspaces and erasing entire line.

Answer (score 1):

I found this one that solves this problem:

```
export PS1='\[\e[0;35m⌘\e[m \e[0;36m\w/\e[m \e[0;33m`git branch 2> /dev/null | grep -e ^* | sed -E s/^\\\\\*\ \(.+\)$/\(\\\\\1\)\ /`\e[m\] → '
```

Very convenient for my git work! (Feel free to remove the arrow at the end, seems kinda useless).

Credits go out to this guy:
https://gist.github.com/clozed2u/4971506#file-gistfile1-sh